# UV, Modify UV island when modifying mesh

Tags: uv

I saw somewhere that there was an option in Blender that allows you to modify the UV map at the same time you modify the topology of the object.

I remember seeing a video where a box working as a wall had some faces extended to make the wall larger. In that video, the UV islands for those walls extended at the same time so the texture proportion wasn't affected.

I can't find how to do it?

Apologies if I have just dreamed it but I remember clearly and it is really frustrating I cant find how to do it after googling for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're talking about the *Correct Face Attributes* option which will change the UV as soon as you change the topology:

[image]

Also, when you slide an edge, make sure you have the *Correct UVs* option enabled in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Comment: It was just that.
Thanks so much :)